# Add select onchange with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm a newbie to Javascript so I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I want to add an extra select when a previous select is changed. I know my code should look something likes this but it isn't working:

```
$(function(){
$('#artist').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "artist_field.php",
        dataType:"html",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
           $('#artist').append(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML

```
<td id="artist">
<select name="artist_1" id="artist">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</td>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get the values in artist_field.php that I'm trying to send (because I'm trying to exclude the previous selected option in the new select). I hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show your php file, and also show us your result.

Comment: Maybe you could have the second select hidden and just show it when it matches the value of the first

Comment: By the way, you have the same id for the td tag and the select, you should change one of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select_2').hide();
    $('#artist').change(function(){
        $('#select_2').show();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<td id="artist">
    <select name="artist_1" id="artist">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select name="select_2" id="select_2">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</td>
```

It will only show the second select if you chose something on the first one

Answer (score 2):

**Update: I just noticed that you have the ID artist in the code twice. You might change the TD to `<td id="artist_td">` or something for my example to work**

To send the currently selected option back to the server in the post, you can do something like:

```
$('#artist').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "artist_field.php",
        data: { "value": $("#artist").val() },
        dataType:"html",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
           $('#artist').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Then in the PHP document, you can get the value with `$_POST["value"];`, and use that value to limit the return options.

**update**

If you are going to fire the change event off multiple times, it's going to append the new data every time. If this is not the behavior that you want, add a `div` or something to put the new data into like:

```
<td id="artist_td">
<select name="artist_1" id="artist">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
<div id="newdata"></div>
</td>
```

Then edit the success function

```
success: function(data){
   $('#newdata').empty().append(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With "artist_field.php" returning a string containing all elements to place in the <select> element separated by commas. I hope it will help ☻ ☺

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var list = document.getElementById("artist");
    var xhr = Xhr();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        if(xhr.status === 4 || xhr.status === 200)
        {
            var results = (xhr.responseText).split(',');
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i)
            {
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.innerHTML = results[i];
                list.appendChild(el);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "artist_field.php", false);
    xhr.send(null);
}, false);

function Xhr()
{
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    }catch(e){}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }catch(e){}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){}
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){}
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code where you can easily understand `select` Tag `on change` with `ajax` request using `PHP`.

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select SMS Template</label>
    <select id="sms-select" name="sms-select" onchange="smschange(this.value)" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select SMS Template</option>
            <?php foreach ($sms as $row) { ?>
                <option value="1">Sample SMS</option>
                <option value="2">Test SMS</option> 
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>
    function smschange(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {'id': id},
            url: 'sms.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res){
               alert(res);
            },
            error: function(res){
                $('#message').text('Error!');
                $('.dvLoading').hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

JQuery Library Source Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```